# Definitions of conditional probability and intersection of events circular reasoning

Tags: probability, probability-theory

My text defines the two topics in the following way:

**Independence**
$Pr[A |B] = \frac{Pr[A \cap B]}{Pr[B]} = \frac{Pr[A]\times Pr[B]}{Pr[B]} = Pr[A]$

This makes sense to me because $Pr[B]$ cancels out. However, where did $Pr[A \cap B] = Pr[A]\times Pr[B]$ come from in the first place? There's another section called intersection of events that has something like this:

**Intersection of events**
$Pr[A \cap B] = Pr[A]Pr[B|A]$

I understand that you can rearrange the definition of $Pr[A|B]$ to set it in equal to $Pr[A \cap B]$ but if both definitions are saying the same thing in different ways, where does $Pr[A] \times Pr[B]$ come from? Seems like circular reasoning to the untrained eye.

Comment: By **definition** events $A$ and $B$ are independent if $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

Comment: So, the intersection of events $Pr[A \cap B] = Pr[A]Pr[B|A]$ will only equal $Pr[A \cap B]= Pr[A]Pr[B]$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent but the definition of independence already assumes the fact that $Pr[A \cap B] = Pr[A]Pr[B]$

Comment: It is not circular reasoning, they are simply equivalent definitions. Each one implies the other.

Comment: Probabilists find it useful to have a word for events $A$ and $B$ for which $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. That word is **independent**.

Comment: I guess I'm having trouble seeing how "one implies the other" is not circular

Comment: So can we say that independence is a specific case of intersection of events? Maybe my text shouldn't have presented them in the above order

Comment: The equation labeled with "intersection of events" actually directly come from the elementary definition of conditional probability. It will holds for all conditional probability. The one above, as said, is directly come from the definition of independence.